# Set a consistent style to all EditText (for e.g.)

Tags: android

I'm trying to make all `EditText`'s in my application have a consistent look. I'm aware that I can do something like this:

```
<style name="App_EditTextStyle">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/filled_roundededges_box_dark</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#808080</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">45dip</item>
</style>
```

Then I can make a particular `EditText` have this style by doing this:

```
<EditText ...
    style="@style/App_EditTextStyle
    ...>
```

But this way I have to remember to set the style individually for each and every `EditText` in my application which is tedious, if not error prone.

Is there some way I could make this a part of a theme or something? This is so I don't have to associate this style to every `EditText`. Something like this fictitious code block:

```
<style name="App_Theme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
   ... 
   <item name="android:EditTextSyle">@style/App_EditTextStyle</item>
   ...
<style>
```

And then in my `AndroidManifest.xml` I have something like:

```
<application
    ....
    android:theme="@style/App_Theme">
```

And Voila! all my `EditText`'s have the consistent style without me having to specify the style for each instance.

Answer (score 167, accepted):

Override the attribute pointing to the `EditText` style(named `editTextStyle` :) ) in your custom theme:

```
<style name="App_Theme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
   <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/App_EditTextStyle</item>
</style>
```

and make your custom style to extend `Widget.EditText`:

```
<style name="App_EditTextStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.EditText">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/filled_roundededges_box_dark</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#808080</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">45dip</item>
</style>
```

Edit:

If you're using the much newer AppCompat related themes use the editTextStyle attribute without the android prefix:

```
<style name="App_Theme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="editTextStyle">@style/App_EditTextStyle</item>
</style>
```

Comment: This sounds so plausible and logical, yet it doesn't seem to work for me. Could I be missing something?

Comment: @ManishGupta How exactly doesn't work? I've tested the styles above and they work, BUT the `layout_height/height` can't be put in there because android probably checks for those attributes before the theme's styles and it will complain about them missing. But a custom drawable + different text color work with the above.

Comment: I have things set up exactly as you describe. There is no point in me reposting. I'm giving this to you anyway. I am missing something somewhere. What you prescribe is cold logic and should work. I'll revisit this after cooling off. Thanks.

Comment: This gives me a:  No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:editTextSyle'

Comment: @Zainodis I don't see how that would happen, that style is available(on which android version are you trying to use it?). Try to refresh or clean your project and see if you don't have other xml errors.

Comment: @Luksprog After lots of refreshing and cleaning the error disappeared, but re-appeared occasionally. My Min SDK Version is 10, Target SDK Version was 14 at the time (11 now). My main issue is, that the app looks different on SDK 10 devices than it looks on SDK 11/14 devices. And it also depends on which device it is. The Note has a dark background (while the Xperia S has a white background) in it's EditTexts, so dark text color wouldn't work, unless we also change the background color of the AutoCompleteTextView... It's a joy. We've now decided to control the complete look from top to bottom.

Comment: @Zainodis Welcome to the wonderful world of Android various looks across devices and API versions. If you want a unified look and feel for all platforms and devices then go with making your own complete theme(instead of relying on the sdk provided look(which manufacturers modify as they please)).

Comment: Hey @Luksprog, is the `android:editTextStyle` supposed to apply to `AutoCompleteTextViews` as well as `EditTextViews`?  Because I tried and its not working for styling my `AutoCompleteTextView`.  How would you style an `AutoCompleteTextView`?  And I'm not talking about the drop down, I just want to apply a colored Holo underline to the `AutoCompleteTextView`.

Comment: @toobsco42 `edittextStyle` doesn't apply to an `AutoCompleTextView`(although it's an `EditText`). Have a look at the `autoCompleteTextViewStyle` attribute in the theme.xml which points to a `Widget.AutoCompleTextView` style in the style.xml file.

Comment: thanks @Luksprog ya i just noticed the `autoCompleteTextViewStyle` attribute in `themes.xml`.

Comment: Okay I did exactly the same thing but nothing happened. I was using Theme.Light instead of Theme.Holo therefore I changed that as well

Here is my code:-
 <style name="app_editTextStyle" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light">
        <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/myEditTextStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="myEditTextStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.EditText">
        <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
        <item name="android:background">#342322</item>
    </style>

Comment: @Jadoon please post a new question mentioning all the details. Also make sure you actually apply that them to your application or activities.

Comment: I like this solution, but unfortunately it does not support every style attribute.. specifically of interest - margins are not available with this approach apparently - described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13365288/2162226 . "Short Answer: If you are specifying layout_margin in a custom style, this style must be explicitly applied to each individual view that you wish to have the specified margin"

Comment: Doesn't work for me too. But if i change `<item name="android:editTextStyle">` to `<item name="editTextStyle">`, it's ok. Thanks!

Comment: When using `AppCompat` remove the `android:` prefix. Apply to not only this but many other attributes.

Comment: In 2019, it works smoothly at Android Studio 3.4.1. However I had to add `android:` prefix, So we have:  `<item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/App_EditTextStyle</item>` . It's the only way to disable select handles in `EditText` controls, because *Android* just add the routines in API v.29

Answer (score 56):

@Luksprog answer is correct but not working for me. After some experimentation, I found out that removing the android namespace from editTextStyle made it work for me.

```
<style name="App_Theme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
   <item name="editTextStyle">@style/App_EditTextStyle</item>
</style>
```

and make your custom style to extend `Widget.EditText` or if using the AppCompat theme `Widget.AppCompat.EditText`:

```
<style name="App_EditTextStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.EditText">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/filled_roundededges_box_dark</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#808080</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">45dip</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Works for me too. But why it behaves like this ?

Comment: Might have something to do with the `AppCompat` library. Does your activity extend `AppCompatActivity`? Oh the mysteries of Android development.

Comment: @MattZukowski did some digging based on your comment - probable culprit: From `AppCompat v7:21+` onwards the standard theme attributes needs to be used without the "android:" prefix in the styles.

Comment: Thankkkss for this.

Comment: Works fine even without using Widget.AppCompat.EditText .. But I can not access Widget.AppCompat.EditText. Says "can not resolve symbol '@android:style/Widget.AppCompat.EditText'"

Comment: Same story for me. I'm using both `AppCompatActivity` and the `AppCompatEditText`. Had to get rid of `android:` namespace...

Answer (score 18):

First, define the style for your EditText. Make sure that the parent style is `android:Widget.EditText`

```
<style name="CustomEditTextStyle" parent="android:Widget.EditText">

    <item name="android:textColor">#0F0F0F</item>
    <!-- ... More items here if needed ... -->
</style>
```

After that, override the attribute `android:editTextStyle` in your custom theme. Be aware, if you are using the support library, you will also need to override the attribute `editTextStyle` (without the android namespace).

```
<style name="App_Theme" parent="...">
   <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/CustomEditTextStyle</item>
   <item name="editTextStyle">@style/CustomEditTextStyle</item> <!-- For compatibility with the support library -->
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to set a few simple parameters, like text color, the Android namespace has a few parameters that will do that without the need to declare a separate style for the edit text. Eg

```
<style name="MyStyle" parent="android:Theme.Material.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/black</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:editTextColor">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:editTextBackground">@color/black</item>
    ....
</style>
```

Comment: For newer version of AppCompat use `editTextColor` and remove `android:`.

Answer (score -1):

```
<style name="App_Theme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">    
    <item name="android:editTextBackground">@drawable/filled_roundededges_box_dark</item>
</style>
```