# Android; define theme for specific View subclass within Activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-theme

is there a way to define a style that affects all Views in an Activity of a given type, without editing all of the xml View tags to define the style.  is there a way to define something like "all TextViews in this Activity have a minHeight of 70sp"?

Comment: Something  like a custom theme(only for that particular activity) for which you set the desired views attributes?

Comment: well, yes, i think.  but i want to style/theme only Views of a specific type.  i'm trying to avoid explicitly defining the style for each TextView instance, as it just seems like there ought to be a way to do this.  and if there isn't, there should be.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10903647/set-a-consistent-style-to-all-edittext-for-e-g. Worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A theme is what you want. Each android widget has a default style that you could override to make it as you want. For example:

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <style name="TextViewSpecial" parent="@android:style/Theme">
        <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/SpecialTextView</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

a theme that overrides the style for a `TextView`. `SpecialTextView` is a style like this:

```
<style name="SpecialTextView" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:minHeight">70sp</item> <!-- use dp instead of sp --       
</style>
```

Then simply set the `TextViewSpecial` theme in the manifest to the desired activity. You can use this method to ovreride the style of what widget you want.

Answer (score 0):

Just define a theme for the layout.