# Change line under EditText in unfocused state

Tags: android, android-edittext

How to change default color of the line (I don't know how it's called exactly) under EditText in unfocused state. If view's background color - black, this line invisible.

Comment: You can try playing with themes. Some description [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10903647/set-a-consistent-style-to-all-edittext-for-e-g