# Removing the left padding on an Android EditText

Tags: android, android-layout

The default EditText background seems to put ~ 4dp of padding on the left. This causes misalignment with other widgets.

I made a simple app to demonstrate. Screenshot:

[image: Left padding on EditText]

Layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <TextView
        android:background="#00ff00"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="HINT"
        android:text="TEXT"
        android:singleLine="true"/>
    <TextView
        android:background="#00ff00"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Is there anyway to stop it from doing this?

Answer (score 13):

One workaround is to use negative margin on the sides (-4dp)

This will only work when the EditText background matches the Layout background, and you don't have anything on the sides in the Layout that would be covered by the EditText

Comment: actually this is the most hassle-free solution. sad. but true. idk why does google made it this way. seems horribly useless.

Answer (score 7):

Did you try adding android:background="@android:color/transparent"?

I did the same example with this result

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <TextView
        android:background="#00ff00"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="HINT"
        android:text="TEXT"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:singleLine="true"/>
    <TextView
        android:background="#00ff00"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

**Second way with lines**

Add an xml file in drawable like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" /> <!--background color of box-->
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:top="-2dp"
        android:right="-2dp"
        android:left="-2dp">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#000000" />  <!-- color of stroke -->
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

then in your layout add this in your EditText android:background="@drawable/edittext_background"

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <TextView
        android:background="#00ff00"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="HINT"
        android:text="TEXT"
        android:background="@drawable/edittext_background"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:background="#00ff00"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

and you will have this
[image]

Comment: Right, but now it doesn't look like an EditText. Part of the reason I want to use an EditText is that it has the line which changes on focus etc 'for free'

Comment: Ooo nice with the drawable. What about color changes based on state?

Comment: You can change with any color in android:color="#000000" />  <!-- color of stroke --> For example: android:color="#DD0000"

Comment: Sure, but with a selector? Or would I need to make a drawable for each state and reference them all in a selector? Still a lot better than needing to modify nine-patches/programatically tint for each color

Comment: you would just need one more xml file to define the color as a selector

Answer (score 4):

Use `android:layout_marginLeft="-4dp"` in edit text field as follows.

```
<EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="HINT"
        android:text="TEXT"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-4dp"
        android:singleLine="true"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

This issue comes from the default value of `?android:attr/editTextBackground`.

```
<inset xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:insetBottom="@dimen/abc_edit_text_inset_bottom_material"
    android:insetLeft="@dimen/abc_edit_text_inset_horizontal_material"
    android:insetRight="@dimen/abc_edit_text_inset_horizontal_material"
    android:insetTop="@dimen/abc_edit_text_inset_top_material">

    <selector>
        <item android:state_enabled="false">
            <nine-patch
                android:alpha="?android:attr/disabledAlpha"
                android:src="@drawable/abc_textfield_default_mtrl_alpha"
                android:tint="?attr/colorControlNormal" />
        </item>
        <item
            android:state_focused="false"
            android:state_pressed="false">
            <nine-patch
                android:src="@drawable/abc_textfield_default_mtrl_alpha"
                android:tint="?attr/colorControlNormal" />
        </item>
        <item>
            <nine-patch
                android:src="@drawable/abc_textfield_activated_mtrl_alpha"
                android:tint="?attr/colorControlActivated" />
        </item>
    </selector>

</inset>
```

As you can see the inset value for all edges of EditText is `abc_edit_text_inset_top_material = 4dp`. That makes EditText has small padding around its content.
To remove that padding you should create a new EditText style with modified `editTextBackground` attribute. For example:

```
<style name="Widget.App.TextField" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.EditText">
        <item name="colorControlActivated">#303E44</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">#E5E9EC</item>
        <item name="colorControlNormal">#E5E9EC</item>
        <item name="editTextBackground">@drawable/background_new_edit_text</item>
<item name="android:editTextBackground">@drawable/background_new_edit_text</item>
    </style>
```

New `background_edit_text.xml` (Remember to put this file into correct drawable directory so it will not be overried such as drawable-v21...)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<inset xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:inset="@dimen/spacing_0dp">
    <selector>
        <item android:state_enabled="false">
            <nine-patch
                android:alpha="?android:attr/disabledAlpha"
                android:src="@drawable/abc_textfield_default_mtrl_alpha"
                android:tint="?attr/colorControlNormal" />
        </item>
        <item
            android:state_focused="false"
            android:state_pressed="false">
            <nine-patch
                android:src="@drawable/abc_textfield_default_mtrl_alpha"
                android:tint="?attr/colorControlNormal" />
        </item>
        <item>
            <nine-patch
                android:src="@drawable/abc_textfield_activated_mtrl_alpha"
                android:tint="?attr/colorControlActivated" />
        </item>
    </selector>

</inset>
```

Apply new style to your `EditText`:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/edt_phone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/Widget.App.TextField"
        />
```

Comment: Thx for sharing, looks like a good approach. It doesn't work for me though. Setting `editTextBackground` has no effect on the style, I tried with other background just to be sure. If I use `android:editTextBackground` then I get the no-inset-background, but I lose the colors, and can no longer use `colorControlActivated`. I havn't yet found the right way to set the colors. Perhaps its a theme-thing, and my app theme overrides it (if such is possible) ?  PS: I also updated the style reference, a small typo.

Comment: Yes, in your case it could be a theme-thing. With mine, I still can change the `colorControlActivated` of the EditText.
Note: to remove the `inset` of EditText on Android 30 the attribute should be `android:editTextBackground` (you can use both for sure).

Comment: I still don't know why it didn't work. Maybe of relevance, I'm using material design `com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-rc01`. Also (for old troubled souls) here are lots of others who had issue with getting styles to work on EditText: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10904193/197141

Comment: Ahh I found the problem. I believe you have unwittingly omitted the correct background file. The file you included is the default 'editTextBackground' from android source/drawable but it overwritten by drawable-v21. If you have it working you must have included the v21 version setting the colors and which look like this: https://chromium.googlesource.com/android_tools/+/master/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/drawable-v21/abc_edit_text_material.xml

Can you confirm this is true (and update the answer)?

Comment: @arberg Yes, I referenced to the file in `drawable` folder instead of `drawable-v21`. Just updated my answer.
Here is my sample code in case you need it: https://github.com/hoanv810/EditTextSample

Answer (score 2):

Change background of EditText to custom, it have nine-patch padding

Comment: Yeah I guess that would work, though I would prefer not to need to make a nine-patch for each state (or need to put this logic in every app that wants to use an EditText...)

Comment: Then try to apply padding for TextViews?

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm doing, it is a gross hack though. Hoping for a cleaner solution

Comment: In any case EditText with default background will be have small padding

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer (maybe a small sample would be helpful). It just seems to be what it is, the default background for EditText has insets all around it. Everything else would indeed be a hack, IMHO.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to align only the text and not the line underneath, you can overwrite the padding programmatically.

So let's say this layout is for an activity. Once the activity has been created you can do something like:

```
findViewById(R.id.edit_text).setPaddding(
                                 0,
                                 old_top_paddding,
                                 old_right_paddding,
                                 old_bottom_padding);
```

The key is to re-set the padding once the background has been applied. You might need to watch for cases where the background is set again, so maybe one idea is to override the `setBackground*()` methods and re-set the padding there.