# How to underline an EditText

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, underline

I am having some problems to underline an EditText in AndroidStudio.

This is what I am looking for (this is just a photo, not my real text):

[image: example screenshot]

But I do not really know any property to do that.

My code right now is really simple. Just the "normal" one:

```
 <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:id="@+id/tx_titulo"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:text="@string/pt_titulo"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:allowUndo="true"
        />
```

I do not want to underline just the text (in this case "Título"), but the whole PlainText

Does anybody know it?
Greets.

Comment: Doesn't the default already have that? What's your edit text code look like?

Comment: Sorry, I edit the question.

Comment: You probably have the width set to wrap_content. Without the XML layout it is hard to help. Try setting it to match_parent, should do the trick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is default, but try to check your styles. Maybe there is a style that will override the style in the whole application. If there is, just remove it

Comment: You were right. It is basically done by default. When I checked the behavior of my application in my phone, it worked.

Comment: @MarioLópezBatres anytime :)

Answer (score 3):

To do this programatically, you could find an answer in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28310397/7086415).

To set the underline color:

```
editText.getBackground().setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```

To remove the underline color:

```
editText.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
```

To do it from the XML, you could add background property to do the same thing in your layout.xml with any drawable resource as a background by adding:

`android:background="@drawable/mydrawable"`

If you have a couple of EditText with the same style configuration, to avoid setting the attribute to each EditText, you could override EditText's default attributes, defining a custom style like it is done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10904193/7086415).

Comment: But, is adding a drawable background to each Textview the unique solution?

Comment: I guess you meant EditText, not Textview. No, you don't have to add background attribute to each EditText. I have edited the answer with a comment on how to custom style the default EditText to avoid that.