# How is the line under the text of an EditText created?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-background

By default `android.widget.EditText` has a line under its text. How exactly is that technically done? I checked the [source code](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/core/java/android/widget/EditText.java) of the `EditText` class, but couldn't find where this is done?

I think to know that the line is technically a background, but where is this background set? And especially, as it's just a background, how does Android ensure that this line is drawn below the text and not behind it? Answers with proofs / links to source highly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, this underline is a background, which is probably `ColorStateList` (e.g. it changes color when pressed), but if you run your code on Android 4.x or older (pre Material Design) then this background is fixed bitmap/drawable

`EditText` have an `android:background` attribute, but it is also present for all other `View`s. so it is set inside source code of `View`, not extending `EditText`. and pointer to the proper drawable of background is set by styling/theming (in [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10903647/set-a-consistent-style-to-all-edittext-for-e-g) you have some example)

`EditText` is using `TextPaint` (`getPaint` method) which may be used to add some extra spacing between/over/under/next to letters to ensure not-overlaying. also drawable may have `padding` attribute - may draw line in last row of pixels but set bottom padding to `1px` and that ensures that content of this `View` (in this case `EditText`) will not be drawn under/over padding (but drawable does) - sooner `View` will expand a bit if have `wrap_content` for height

sorry for not-so-precise answer, topic needs more inwestigation and searching in sources, but maybe my points will help you find answers by yourself

Comment: thank you, that gave me very good starting points. Found the style defining the `editTextStyle` attribute (searched up in he hierarchy starting with my AppTheme) and also the `editTextBackground` attribute. So I can now study the drawable referenced by `editTextBackground`  attribute to understand it.